# Geoserver Rest API update workspace name

Tags: php, rest, curl, geoserver

I am trying to update workspace name through geoserver rest api using put method.

I am getting "Can't change the name of a workspace." error.

This is my code.

```
 $service = geoserver_url;
$data = "<workspace><name>testnew</name></workspace>";
        $url = $service . "rest/workspaces/workspacename";
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $passwordStr = username:password
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $passwordStr);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/xml"););
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');   
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    Any kind of help appreciated.
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not an allowable operation (as mentioned in the [manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/workspaces.html#workspaces-ws-format)). Any `PUT` that changes the name of a workspace returns a 403 Error.

All you can do is create a new workspace, copy the contents of the old one and then delete it.

Answer (score 0):

According to geoserver REST API documentations ([link](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/latest/en/api/1.0.0/workspaces.yaml)), you can simply edit workspace name (ws_name) by **putting** a request which has an xml string data in its body.

Here I've given you an example. Because of using Express as my application sever I've implemented a request using javascript but it can be changed to your favorite syntax.

```
const options = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/{current_ws_sname}',
  method: 'PUT',
  headers: { 'Content-type': 'text/xml' },
  body: '<workspace><name>{new_ws_name}</name></workspace>',
  auth: {
     user: {geoserver_username},
     pass: {geoserver_password}
  }
```

and for executing the request based on above option variable I've used request function in Express:

```
request(options, (error, response, body) => {
  console.log('response status code:' , response.statusCode)
  console.log('response status message: ', response.statusMessage)
  const result = {}
  if (!error) {
     const statusCode = response.statusCode;
     const statusMessage = response.statusMessage;
     if (statusCode == 200) {
         result.err = false
         result.msg = `Modified`
     } else if (statusCode == 404) {
         result.err = true
         result.msg = 'Workspace not found!'
     } else if (statusCode == 405) {
         result.err = true
         result.msg = 'Forbidden to change the name of the workspace!'
                      //because of your username and/or password
     } else if (statusCode == 500) {
         result.err = true
         result.msg = 'Server internal error or duplicate names'
     }
  } else {
     result.err = true,
     result.msg = error;
  }
  res.send(result);
})
```

Don't forget to replace **{current_ws_sname}**, **{new_ws_sname}**, **{geoserver_username}**, **{geoserver_password}** by your own values.

All the possible situations have been mentioned as above (i.e. 200, 404, 405, 500) and there is no error message like "*Can't change the name of a workspace.*" in geoserver documentations!

What statusCode and statusMessage do you get in response? Can you confirm that your {new_ws_sname} isn't duplicate?